# Crank-Nicolson method for inhomogeneous advection equation

Tags: pde, finite-difference, hyperbolic-pde, advection, crank-nicolson

Suppose we have the **inhomogeneous** advection equation
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)u(t,x)=v(t,x)$$
for $u,v:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (with boundary conditions not yet specified).

Assuming that we had no $v$, i.e. the homogeneous part of the equation, the Crank-Nicolson method would yield

$$-c\frac{\mu}{4}u^{n+1}_{\ell-1}+u^{n+1}_{\ell}+c\frac{\mu}{4}u^{n+1}_{\ell+1}=c\frac{\mu}{4}u^n_{\ell-1}+u^n_{\ell}-c\frac{\mu}{4}u^n_{\ell+1},$$

where $\mu=\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$ and $u^n_\ell=u(n\Delta t,\ell\Delta x)$.

I don't know how to deal with the inhomogeneity in these schemes though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your equation can be written in the following fashion (any spatial derivative approximation is valid), once space is discretised:
$$\frac{1}{c}\frac{du_i}{dt}=-\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_i(t) + v_i(t) \tag{*}$$
Keep in mind that $v_i(t) = v(x_i,t)$.

Now the system of equations depends only on time $t$ you can apply Crack Nicholson method to solve the system of ODEs. Fo simplicity let the rght hand side of $(*)$ be named as:
$$F_i(t) = v_i(t)-\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_i(t) $$
and therefore $(*)$ cab ne rewritten as follows:
$$\frac{1}{c}\frac{du_i}{dt}=F_i(t) \tag{**}$$

The Cranck-Nicholson method can be deduced from a $\theta$ method setting $\theta=1/2$, therefore, the time discretised equation $(**)$ is:

$$\frac{1}{c}\frac{u_i^{n+1}-u_i^{n}}{\delta t}=\theta\, F_i(t^{n+1}) + (1-\theta)F_i(t^n)=\frac{1}{2}\left[ F_i(t^{n+1})+F_i(t^n)\right]$$

Do not forget that we had the expression for $F_i(t)$, in which the function $v_i(t)$ is also present.

Hope you now know how to deal with that term.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but suppose we want to propagate the equation in $x$, then I guess discretising the $t$ axis would yield: $$u^{n+1}_i=u^n_i+\frac{\Delta x}{2}(F_i(x^{n+1})+F_i(x^n)),$$ where $$F_i(x)=v_i(x)-\frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_i(x),$$ right?

Comment: I think you want to solve the system in a Lagrangian frame of reference?, where your equation is simply: $$\frac{du(t,x(t))}{dt}=v(t,x(t))$$ with $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=c$$. In this case you only have the path of a single particle through time. The time only goes forwards, you must provide an initial condition $u(0,x)=u^0(x)$ and then solve for the next time. You can not solve time before space.

Comment: For implementation and the $F_i(t)$ term, I guess I would have to discretise the differential operator using a finite difference approximation and assign an initial condition for $v$?

Comment: $v$ is a given function of time. Imagine that $u=\exp{(-t)}\sin{x}$, for example. You must only provide an initial condition for $u$

Comment: If I deal with the $F_i(t)$ term by applying the Euler forward method on $\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_i(t)\sim \frac{u^n_{i+1}-u^n_i}{\delta x}$ then I get $$u^{n+1}_i=cu^n_i+c\frac{\delta t}{2}\left[v^{n+1}_i-v^n_i-\frac{u^{n+1}_{i+1}-u^{n+1}_i+u^n_{i+1}-u^n_i}{\delta x}\right],$$ since, for example, $$F_i(t^{n+1})=v^{n+1}_i-\frac{u^{n+1}_{i+1}-u^{n+1}_i}{\delta x},$$ however, I don't think we can solve this

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is that I need a finite difference matrix

Comment: Yes you do need to solve : $T\vec{u}^{n+1}=\vec{F}(\vec{u}^n, \vec{v}^{n+1},\vec{v}^n)$ where $T$ is a matrix and $\vec{u}$ is the collection of $u_i$ arranged in a vector.

Comment: Well, writing it in matrix form yields $$\begin{pmatrix}u^{n+1}_1\\u^{n+1}_2\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}=c\begin{pmatrix}u^n_1\\u^n_2\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}+\frac{c\delta t}{2}\left(\begin{pmatrix}v^{n+1}_1\\v^{n+2}_2\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}v^n_1\\v^n_2\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\Delta x}\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&&\\&\ddots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u^{n+1}_1\\u^{n+1}_2\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\delta x}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1 & \\ &\ddots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}\right)$$ I don't know how I would derive $T$ from that though?

Comment: Add the vector in your LHS to the 4th vector in the RHS to obtain $$\vec{u}^{n+1}+ M\vec{u}^{n+1}=(I+M)\vec{u}^{n+1}=T\vec{u}^{n+1}$$ and invert $T$. The matrix $M$ is the one with coefficient  $c\delta t/(2\delta x)$

Comment: So $M$ is the diagonal matrix with that coefficient and diagonal entries 1 and -1

Comment: Yes it is, although the resulting matrix is banded and not diagonal.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that it's $$M=\frac{c\delta t}{2\delta x}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & \\ & -1 & 1 & \\ & & \ddots & \ddots \end{pmatrix}$$?

Comment: Yes you are right!